# Angular 4 prevent template to be loaded, only after certain event

Tags: angular

I have a small webapp. **Every component** is inheriting from `BaseComponent`.

`BaseComponent` on its constructor check if the user is loggedin. (send a request to the server).

On order to avoid dom flickering, I want to pause the template untill the login check is finished.

How can I do that on the following constructor?

Thanks

```
export class BaseComponent{
      constructor(protected http : HttpClient, protected tokenService : CsrfTokenService,protected router: Router) {
        http.get( environment.apiServer + "customer/state",{withCredentials  : true}).subscribe((res : any) => {
              console.log("login result", res);
          if(res.logged_in == false && !this.router.url.toLowerCase().includes("login") && !this.router.url.toLowerCase().endsWith("register")){
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            console.log("redirecting to login");
          }
        });
       }
    }
```

Comment: Learn about route guards: https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the better way to address this is to use angular routing, rather than restricting access in base component that all components inherited from (it is not the right way in my opinion), and restrict access to a feature area based on who the user is. For details on this approach see https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication

Comment: I see now that R. Richards comment the same before my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches for the scenario, I think the simplest approach would be transforming the business into the template. I mean the base class checks if the user is logged in or not and set an property like `userIsLoggedIn` and the template check the property for rendering.

```
<div *ngIf="userIsLoggedIn">
 ...Your page...
</div>
```

In this way you have more flexible User Interface. For example you could show a message or a `Progress Bar` during the waiting and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use routing guards which will check weather a route should be activated or not. canActivate is the guard which can be use for this purpose. below is the url for reference video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DG1lbuu8wt4